# How to get foreign key relation array in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have country table and its translation table with foreign key `country_id`, and city table with foreign key `country_id`, and city translation table with foreign key `city_id`.
So my model.py like this.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Country(models.Model):
    #id             = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    iso_code    = models.CharField(max_length=2, unique=True)
    slug        = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    is_featured = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'rh_countries'

class CountryTranslation(models.Model):
    country     = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    locale      = models.CharField(max_length=2)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'rh_countries_translations'

class City(models.Model):
    country     = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'rh_cities'

class CityTranslation(models.Model):
    city        = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    locale      = models.CharField(max_length=2)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'rh_city_translations'
```

And my views.py file like this.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from home.models import Country, CountryTranslation, City, CityTranslation
from django.db.models import F, Count

def index(request):
    #return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
    template = loader.get_template('home/index.html')
    context = {
        "countries" : Country.objects.filter(
                            is_featured=1,
                            countrytranslation__locale='en'
                        ).annotate(
                            name=F('countrytranslation__name'),
                            totalCities=Count('city', distinct=True)
                        )
    }
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', context)
```

This way I have got total cities of the country. But I want list of 3 cities name of all country with locale `en`.
Please help me to retrieve data such way. 
sample output should be:

```
Array{
    0 => {
        id => 1
        name => 'Australia',
        is_featured => 1,
        totalCities => 5,
        cities => {
            0 => {
                id => 1,
                name => 'Sydney',
                locale => 'en'
            },
            1 => {
                id => 2,
                name => 'Melbourne',
                locale => 'en'
            },
            2 => {
                id => 3,
                name => 'Perth',
                locale => 'en'
            }
        }
    },
    2 => {
        id => 2
        name => 'Spain',
        is_featured => 1,
        totalCities => 12,
        cities => {
            0 => {
                id => 9,
                name => 'Madrid',
                locale => 'en'
            },
            1 => {
                id => 10,
                name => 'Bercelona',
                locale => 'en'
            },
            2 => {
                id => 11,
                name => 'Valencia',
                locale => 'en'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "*But I want list of 3 cities name of all country. Please help me to retrieve data such way.*", it is not really clear to me what you want. Perhaps providing sample output (and data) can help making the problem statement more clear.

Comment: sample out put i have added, you can check I have added array but it may be object.